# androidx.fragment.app.Fragment cannot be converted to android.app.Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, dependencies, fragment

I have a fragment file. There is an error message

> "error: incompatible types: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment cannot be
> converted to android.app.Fragment.
> fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,
> fragment).addToBackStack(null);"

I know there is something wrong with my build.gradle file but i don't know which dependency should i used. I already read the documentation and questions related but some dependency are deprecated. This is my MainActivity file:

```
package com.example.notesapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        replaceFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance(), true);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean istransition){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if(istransition) {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
    }
}
```

And this is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.notesapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    //material design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    //circle image view
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    //scalable unit text size
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

    //scalable unit size
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

    //room database
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5'

    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
```

Instead of

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Comment: + `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of common one (non-`androidx`)

Answer (score 1):

the question is what is `HomeFragment` - it extends built-in `Fragment` or `androidx` version? it should extend `androidx` version. and then you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager`

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

then your IDE should suggest you to fix imports or even would do it for you - there shouldn't be used any `android.app.Fragment...` imports, only `androidx.fragment...` lines/packages

Comment: my HomeFragment extends Fragment version

Comment: `extends Fragment` , but which? check in imports on top of class file. your error suggests that your `HomeFragment` extends `androidx` version (it should), but you are using built-in `FragmentManager` instead of `androidx` one - `getFragmentManager` without `Support` keyword in the middle. these two versions of `Fragment`s aren't compatible, pick one way.worth to say that built-in `android.app` is currently deprecated so I strongly suggest `androidx` maintained version as lib

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!